# Python3 expandtab on string not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, replace, tabs, spaces

```
AAPL,Feb,16,18,165.00,156.41,8.59,0.32,20998.  
AAPL,Feb,16,18,170.00,156.41,13.59,0.08,10177.  
AAPL,Feb,16,18,135.00,156.41,-21.41,0.18,11243.   
ABX,Feb,16,18,14.00,13.06,0.94,0.1,1251.  
AKS,Feb,16,18,5.00,4.5,0.5,0.05,1428.  

for linet in filein:
    linet = linet.replace(",","\t")
    linet = linet.expandtabs(12)    


123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.   

AAPL        Feb         16          18          165.00      156.41      8.59        0.32        20998.  
AAPL        Feb         16          18          170.00      156.41      13.59       0.08        10177.  
AAPL        Feb         16          18          135.00      156.41      -21.41      0.18        11243.  
ABX         Feb         16          18          14.00       13.06       0.94        0.1         1251.  
AKS         Feb         16          18          5.00        4.5         0.5         0.05        1428.  
AMD         Feb         16          18          12.00       11.31       0.69        0.12        9231.
```

this code seems to use the standard 8 spaces and not 12
have tried many different tab widths still the same

Answer (score 1):

`str.expandtabs(N)` expands a `"\t"` character into *up to* (but not always exactly) `N` spaces to take you to the next *tab stop*. A tab stop in a position at the `(N*i)`th character, where `i` is an integer number. In your example, each column starts at the `(12*i)`th position.

Comment: I found the problem, when viewed in formatted doc the spacing is not standard text spacing